# How to loop php variables?

Tags: php

I have a list of variables like this:

```
<?php 

$hh_1_date="Aug 29, 2012";
$hh_1_title="Data 1";
$hh_1_video="FFFnQGX0";
$hh_1_name="Peter Pan";
$hh_1_company="CompTIA";
$hh_1_image="image1.png";

$hh_1_date="Aug 30, 2012";
$hh_1_title="Data 2";
$hh_1_video="FFFRDEX0";
$hh_1_name="Peter Pooh";
$hh_1_company="CompTIA";
$hh_1_image="image2.png";

?>
```

And then I pull those variables into markup like this - all basic stuff...

```
  <div class="card">
    <img alt="..." class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $hh_1_image?>">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark"><?php echo $hh_1_date ?></span>
      <h5 style="color:#0c0c0e"><?php echo $hh_1_title ?></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But at the moment I am copying and pasting the above HTML and changing the PHP to _2 then _3 then _4 according to its respective PHP Variable which I know is the wrong way of doing it.

So, what is a faster way? I believe it's called looping?

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, you are overwriting your items in your "list of variables". An easier way would be to use [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), which you can then loop over (using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

Comment: Using arrays is definitely the good choice. Meanwhile you can have a look at variable variables in the doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all these variables in array with key value pair and use foreach loop, like this:

```
$arr =[
 [
'date' =>'Aug 30, 2012',
'title' => 'Data 1',
'video' => 'FFFRDEX0',
'name' => 'Peter Pooh',
'company' => 'CompTIA',
'image' => 'image1.png'
],
[
'date' =>'Aug 29, 2012',
'title' => 'Data 2',
'video' => 'FFFRDEX0',
'name' => 'Peter Pooh',
'company' => 'CompTIA',
'image' => 'image2.png'
]
....
.....
......
]

<?php foreach($arr as $k => $v): ?>
 <div class="card">
    <img alt="..." class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $v['image']">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark"><?php echo $v['date'] ?></span>
      <h5 style="color:#0c0c0e"><?php echo $v['title'] ?></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`get_defined_vars`** ([Here is the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)) function. Here is an example.

```php
<?php 
$hh_1_date="Aug 29, 2012";
$hh_1_title="Data 1";
$hh_1_video="FFFnQGX0";
$hh_1_name="Peter Pan";
$hh_1_company="CompTIA";
$hh_1_image="image1.png";

$hh_1_date="Aug 30, 2012";
$hh_1_title="Data 2";
$hh_1_video="FFFRDEX0";
$hh_1_name="Peter Pooh";
$hh_1_company="CompTIA";
$hh_1_image="image2.png";

$vars = get_defined_vars();
foreach($vars as $key => $val){
    print_r($val);
}
?>
```

While iterating through, You'll get the variable name as key and variable's value as the value in a loop. Be careful, This method will also return the global variables defined by PHP(e.g `$_SERVER`, `$_POST` etc). The function **`get_defined_vars`** returns all the variables available in current scope along with it's value.